# Print automatically (PDFMake in Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, printing, pdfmake

I am using PDFMake in Node.js. How can the created PDF file be printed out automatically? So far I can only save the PDF file and I haven't found out how to do that.

Thank you for your help

**EDIT:** 
I did some further research and decided to use Ghostscript.
If you have the same problems I had use this in your Node.js file:

```
require('child_process').exec(__dirname + "/ghostscript.bat", function (err, stdout, stderr) {
if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
}

console.log(stdout);
});
```

And your ghostscript.bat file should look like this:

```
gswin64c -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOSAFER -q -dNumCopies=1 -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile="YOUR_PRINTER_NAME_HERE" "PATH\TO\YOUR\PDF\FILE.pdf"
```

(32 bit: gswin32c)

Comment: Show your code, and what have you tried so far.